# CALayer in NSCollectionViewItem flashes (and disappears) whenever a new item is added in the collection

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

My `NSCollectionViewItem` is in a separate xib file. It has an image view. Previously I was setting image directly on the `NSImageView`. The UI worked fine.

Now, I have added a `CALayer` to `NSImageView`. I use it to display images and transition from from one image to another.

Problem is: each time user adds a new `NSCollectionViewItem`. `CALayers` of `NSCollectionViewItem` blinks/flashes and sometimes disappear altogether. This happens at random. Sometimes `CALayer` of every item disappears. Other times only few items' `CALayer` disappear.

Then if I add another item or resize the `NSCollectionView` by resizing the container Window, which makes `NSCollectionView` to reshuffle all the items. `CALayer` appear back, but not always. This also random. Some items remain CALayer-less.

My guess is that animation of `NSCollectionView` is messing up the `NSCollectionViewItem`'s CALayer.

Any idea what is going on? Is there some sample code/open source project that uses `CALayer` in `NSCollectionViewItem`?

Any help, any tip, no matter how small, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you add the CALayer to the NSImageView?